# Delete all data in MS Access database

Tags: vb.net, excel, ms-access, vba

Here is the code I am using :

```
Try
        Dim SqlQuery As String = "DELETE FROM tblEXcel WHERE ID = " & id & ";"
        Dim SqlCommand As New OleDbCommand

        With SqlCommand
            .CommandText = SqlQuery
            .Connection = conn
            .ExecuteNonQuery()

        End With

    MsgBox("One record deleted..")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, vbOKOnly, "Clear Measurement Table!")
    End Try
```

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow! Please state exactly what your problem is and why your solution seems not to work. Also, put a question in your text (with a question mark and all that :) ).

Comment: Is there any specific error or exception you are getting ?

Answer (score 1):

For DataBindings you can use this...

```
 Do While ExampleBindingSource.Count > 0
     ExampleBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
 Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `WHERE ID = " & id`. Then **ALL** the rows will be deleted.
So, simply change your SQL command to:

```
Dim SqlQuery As String = "DELETE FROM tblEXcel"
```

Answer (score -2):

use below statement:

delete * from tblName

```
Dim SqlQuery As String = "DELETE * FROM tblEXcel WHERE ID = " & id & ";"
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Dim MySQLCON As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Database=test;User ID=root;Password=mysql;")
Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand

MySQLCON.Open() /Open your Connection
Dim DELETERECORD As String = "DELETE * FROM tblEXcel WHERE ID= @id"
COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(DELETERECORD, MySQLCON)
COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", userID.Text) /userID.Text is the string of the users ID
COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()
MySQLCON.Close() /Always Close your Connection
MySQLCON.Dispose() /Always Dispose of your Connection
```

**Note:**

The way you where doing it was vulnerable to MySQL Injection Attacks. If you have a lot of MySQL Code in your application, i advise you to rewrite it in the way so it is not vulnerable.